# EF code first try to drop and create database at web hosting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, hosting

My problem is ef try to re-create the database, but the user does not has this permission, so it breaks the database.

When I try to manual create database, I receive this error:

```
Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.
```

What is the best solution for deploying ef into web hosting?

Comment: If the user has no permission to create a DB, how do the hosting allows you to create it? That's the answer, and the only option, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JotaBe: because I don't have permission, so I must create db by manual, and get this error. Please read carefully my question. Anyway, I change db to Database first, and it works ok in hosting

Comment: Read my comment carefully :) I asked in my answer "how do the hosting allows you to create it?" (the DB), and told you that that's the only way to create it, and thus, the answer to your question. I don't know if you can deploy an mdb adn attach it, or use a control panel, or have access through SSMS or whatever. Depending on what you can do, there are many possible solutions to create update, etc. your DB, and even uses migrations. But I need to know what you're allowed to do.